# Why is the else statement being ignored after a loop?

Tags: python-3.x

Im trying to get the else statement to work after the loop, but upon a 2nd loop it gets ignored and the tickets_left value updates when something other then [Y/N] is entered

## Ticket machine

```
tickets_left = 100

ticket_price = 5

while tickets_left >= 0:

    print("There are {} tickets left".format(tickets_left))

    buy = input("How many tickets would you like to buy: ")

    buy = int(buy)

    price = buy * ticket_price

    confirm = input("Are you sure you would like to buy {} tickets for a total of ${} [Y/N]: ".format(buy,price))

    tickets_left = tickets_left - buy



if confirm.upper() == "Y":
    print("Sold for ${}".format(price))
if confirm.upper() == "N":
    print("Ok")
else:
    print("Please enter either [Y/N] to proceed")
    buy = input("How many tickets would you like to buy: ")
```